# Compare two datarows

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a datatable with multiple rows inside it. I have got 1 more row and I want to check if this row is a duplicate of the existing rows in the datatable. So I tried like:

```
DataTable dataTable = GetTable();
if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var dataRow = dataTable.Rows[i];

        if (dt.Rows.Contains(dataRow) && dt.Rows.Count != 0)  // Giving error
            continue;
        dt.ImportRow(dataRow);
        return dataRow;
    }
}
```

Here, my `dataTable` can also be null/empty for the first time.

But its giving error as:

> Table doesn't have a primary key.

Can anyone help me please. If additional code is required, just comment.

Comment: Does the table you use to read from the database has a [primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933092(v=sql.80).aspx) (in the database itself)? It seems that it doesn't...

Comment: yes it do have a primary key in the database for sure

Comment: What do you get for the property `dataTable.PrimaryKey`?

Comment: see my edit post.....let me check

Comment: when dataTable is empty, `dataTable.PrimaryKey` is giving the same error.

Comment: What size have table? How many rows?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you add the PK on your DataTable object?

I think the code would be something like this:

```
dataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataTable.Columns["Id"] };
```

Comment: its producing the same error as Table doesn't have a primary key. and remember the table is empty for the first time

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dataTable = GetTable();
if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var dataRow = dataTable.Rows[i];

        if (dt.Rows.Contains(dataRow) && dt.Rows.Count != 0)  // Giving error
            continue;
        dt.ImportRow(dataRow);
        return dataRow;
    }
}
```

I assume that your `dt` variable is supposed to be your `dataTable` variable,  if you are getting an error telling you that your table doesn't have a primary key it could be because you are using the wrong variable and that there really isn't a primary key or a table associated with the variable that you are trying to use.

so I assume that the code should look like this instead

```
DataTable dataTable = GetTable();
if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var dataRow = dataTable.Rows[i];

        if (dataTable.Rows.Contains(dataRow) && dataTable.Rows.Count != 0)  // Giving error
            continue;
        dataTable.ImportRow(dataRow);
        return dataRow;
    }
}
```