# compare datarows of different tables

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datatable, datarow

I posted a [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993499/compare-two-datarows/9002025#9002025) some time ago and decided to trim down the complexity of it to let developers answer my main problem. It could be stated as duplicate, but still I want to post it as editing the previous post did not yield much result.

I have 2 datatables: dataTable1 and dataTable2. Both have 1 row with same entries. For eg. columns in both the datatables are Name, Class, Subject. Now both row of both the dataTable are same with values ("John", "5", "Science"). Now I want to compare thses 2 rows if they they have same entries or not. I tried for:

```
if(dataTable1.Rows[0].GetHashCode() == dataTable2.Rows[0].GetHashCode()) 
{ 
    // Result is false (but I expected it to be true) 
}
```

And also tried:

```
if(dataTable1.Rows[0].ItemArray == dataTable2.Rows[0].ItemArray) 
{ 
    // Result is false (but I expected it to be true) 
}
```

I want to avoid loops to do it, but if needed thats fine. I just want to compare the 2 rows of 2 different dataTables that if their entries are same or not. And I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to compare 2 specific rows, or find 2 arbitrary rows that are equal.

Comment: In your code you compare two pointers and so it gives you false.

Comment: for my requirement, I want to compare specific rows. but answer for arbitrary rows should be more appreciated. however I feel, both should have same concept of comparing with different approaches

Comment: pointers? can you describe a bit more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result= dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Intersect(dataTable2.AsEnumerable(),
                                                    DataRowComparer.Default);
```

it returns the records that are in both the table

more info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386998.aspx

Comment: after intersect, it should be `dataTable2` I think.

Comment: in your case if result is not null it means there are the same rocord in both the dable

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso Your answers seems to answer rapslands original question, maybe you should add it in :-) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993499/compare-two-datarows/

Comment: thanks...help me a lot, not sure why I did not go for DataRowComparer

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `Equals` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908019.aspx) of the `DataRowComparer` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907955.aspx) to compare the rows.

Answer (score 4):

Using SequenceEqual to compare two data row as in the following example

```
foreach (DataRow dr in datatable1.Rows)
    foreach (DataRow dr2 in datatable2.Rows)
    {
        if (dr.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(dr2.ItemArray))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dr = dr2");
            //statement                                    
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dr != dr2");
            //statement
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I would normally just cast the item in the `ItemArray` to a string and compare them that way.
From what I remember, using the GetHashCode will **not** bring out the same result as you will find many others will say.
If you have a large number of rows, then you could try creating a class that inherits from `DataRow` and override the Equals method. For example:

    `class CustomRow : DataRow
    {`

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj.GetType() != typeof(CustomRow)) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ItemArray.Length; i++)
            if (((CustomRow)obj)[i] != this[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dataTable1); 
dv.Filter = "SQL query to find specific row"
```

This, naturally, is for every raw you gonna find

Comment: I feel, this is like searching something, not comparing

Comment: compare is search for *similiar* item. it's the same like other solutions, from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The [DataRowComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcomparer-1.equals?view=netframework-4.8) has been available since .NET 3.5, not that you can find an example of how to use it.  Now you can:

```
bool tf;
// Unbelievable...
DataRowComparer<DataRow> drc = DataRowComparer.Default;
DataTable tbl;

tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("One", typeof(string));
tbl.Columns.Add("Two", typeof(string));
tbl.Columns.Add("Three", typeof(string));
tbl.Rows.Add("One", "Two", "Three");
tbl.Rows.Add("One", "Two", "Three");
tbl.Rows.Add("One", "Three", "Two");
tbl.Rows.Add("One", "Two");
tbl.Rows.Add("One", "Two");
tf = dc.Equals(tbl.Rows[0], tbl.Rows[1]);
tf = dc.Equals(tbl.Rows[0], tbl.Rows[2]);
tbl2 = new DataTable();
tbl2.Columns.Add("One", typeof(string));
tbl2.Columns.Add("Two", typeof(string));
tbl2.Columns.Add("Nine", typeof(string));  // Diff col name
tbl2.Rows.Add("One", "Two", "Three");
tbl2.Rows.Add("One", "Two", "Three");
tbl2.Rows.Add("One", "Three", "Two");
tbl2.Rows.Add("One", "Two");
tbl2.Rows.Add("One", "Two");
tf = dc.Equals(tbl.Rows[0], tbl2.Rows[0]);
tf = dc.Equals(tbl.Rows[1], tbl2.Rows[1]);
tf = dc.Equals(tbl.Rows[0], tbl2.Rows[1]);
tf = dc.Equals(tbl.Rows[0], tbl2.Rows[2]);
```

But I like this just as well as jacking around with the DataRowComparer instantiation - I'd need to see be a performance advantage.

```
tbl.Rows[0].ItemArray.SequenceEquals(tbl.Rows[1]);
```