# Comparing datarows and output difference .net 4

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, datarow

I have not used datatables in while.
Is there a way that given 2 datatables or even 1 compare all the rows with the same customerId and output the fieldname and row value that has changed.

Need to compare client data in various stages and find which values have changed.

Any suggestions?

code sample

UPDATED.
I have not found a single question on stackoverflow that shows how to get a difference between 2 tables.
My solution so far but need to find a way to fill the difference object

```
            //Now use Except operator to find the data in first set and not in second
        var userDataFirstSet = oldDt
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Except(newDt.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);

        //Find data in second and not in first
        var userDataSecondSet = newDt
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Except(oldDt.AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);


        List<DataRow> dataRows = userDataFirstSet
            .Union(userDataSecondSet)
            .ToList();

        //Now fill the list with all the differences
       List<Difference>diffs=new List<Difference>();


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Customer[] oldCustomersSet =
            {
                new Customer {CustomerId = 1, Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs", City = "London"},
                new Customer {CustomerId = 2, Name = "Mark", Surname = "Smith", City = "Manchester"},
                new Customer {CustomerId = 3, Name = "Emily", Surname = "Blunt", City = "Liverpool"},
            };

            Customer[] newCustomersSet =
            {
                new Customer {CustomerId = 1, Name = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs", City = "London"},
                new Customer {CustomerId = 2, Name = "Mark", Surname = "Smithyyy", City = "Manchesteraaa"},
                new Customer {CustomerId = 3, Name = "Emily", Surname = "Blunt", City = "Liverpool"},
            };

            DataTable oldDt = GetDataTable(oldCustomersSet);
            DataTable newDt = GetDataTable(newCustomersSet);

            //compare the 2 datatables for each customerId and return ColumnName where the value is different.
            Difference diff=CompareRows(oldDt, newDt);

            /*
           //wanted result is
           Difference diff=new Difference();
           diff.CustomerId = 2;
           diff.FieldName = "Surname";
           diff.OldDataRowValue = "Smith";
           diff.NewDataRowValue = "Smithyyy"
            */

        }

        private static Difference CompareRows(DataTable oldDt, DataTable newDt)
        {
            Difference diff=new Difference();

            //Ideally a generic way to find row values that are different without hardcode the rowName.



            return diff;
        }

        private static DataTable GetDataTable(Customer[] customers)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("CustomerId", typeof(Int32));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Surname", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));

            foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(customer.CustomerId,
                    customer.Name,
                    customer.Surname,
                    customer.City);
            }

            return (table);
        }

    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    public class Difference
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string OldDataRowValue { get; set; }
        public string NewDataRowValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare datarows of different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064485/compare-datarows-of-different-tables)

Comment: sorry this is not a duplicate even if the title implies that. there is no solution there that returns a difference.that would return only true or false.Do not be too quick in saying "it's a duplicate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just loop through the rows, loop through the columns, and look for differences?  I don't think there is a built-in solution in the library.

```
var joined = oldDt.AsEnumerable().Join(newDt.AsEnumerable(), dr => dr.Field<int>("CustomerId"), dr => dr.Field<int>("CustomerId"), (da, db) => Tuple.Create(da, db)).ToList();
var differences = new List<Difference>();
foreach (var entry in joined) {
    var customerId = entry.Item1.Field<int>("CustomerId");
    foreach (var column in oldDt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()) {
        var oldVal = entry.Item1[column.ColumnName];
        var newVal = entry.Item2[column.ColumnName];
        if (!object.Equals(oldVal, newVal)) {
            differences.Add(new Difference { CustomerId = customerId, FieldName = column.ColumnName, OldDataRowValue = Convert.ToString(oldVal), NewDataRowValue = Convert.ToString(newVal) });
        }
    }
}
```

Output of `differences`:

```
CustomerID | FieldName | OldDataRowValue | NewDataRowValue
2          | Surname   | Smith           | Smithyyy
2          | City      | Manchester      | Manchesteraaa
```

Comment: thanks for your time and answer.Kind of close,the only think I dont like about it is that we are hardcoding "customerId".I worked out a different solution myself but need to find a way to ignore certain fields.

Comment: var userDataFirstSet = oldDt.AsEnumerable().Except(newDt.AsEnumerable(),
                                                                       DataRowComparer.Default);
            //Find data in second and not in first
            var userDataSecondSet = newDt.AsEnumerable().Except(oldDt.AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);


            List<DataRow> dataRows = userDataFirstSet.Union(userDataSecondSet).ToList();

Comment: still not there yet as i need to fill a list of difference objects" updated question