# Compare results from two selects using oracle and C#

Tags: c#, oracle, compare

I'm writting a C# application that compares if the result from two different selects are the same and they're execution time, for optimitzing purposes.

Actually I'm using stopwatch to get execution time and then convert OracleDataReaders into DataTable and compare rows, with independency of order, like this:

```
        var tableA = new DataTable();
        tableA.Load(readerA);

        var tableB = new DataTable();
        tableB.Load(readerB);

        bool equals = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableA.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(tableA.Rows[i],tableB.Rows[i]))
            {
                equals = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return equals;
```

But I'm assuming that converting OracleDataReader into DataTable and then using a loop to compare rows are the same and in the same order.

Is there any prebuilt method with C# and Oracle to compare result of two selects with/without rows order?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if `tableBRow == tableARow` will compare the rows in the way that you want. The default `Equals` implementation will compare if the two sides of the equals sign are references to the same object (the same object, created at the same time). Probably you want to compare the value in every column to see if the values are the same. This answer seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064485/compare-datarows-of-different-tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare datarows of different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064485/compare-datarows-of-different-tables)

Comment: @mortb true, I was not comparing objects correctly, updated.

Comment: But my real question is, there's anyway to know if the result of two selects it's the same (with or without order) without converting OracleDataReaders to DataTables and then looping them?

Comment: The answer to your question is not entirely straight forward, it depends on what *exactly* you want to achieve and how much effort you want to lay on your solution. It seems that your solution could be rewritten so it just uses two `OracleDataReaders` looping them by calling `Read()` method on the first `OracleDataReader`, and then the second, loop through the columns on them one by one and compare them until you find any difference. This will be at least somewhat faster as you skip the steps of populating two `DataSets`.

Comment: You will in any case need to have a nested loop for every row.

Comment: Your code makes the assumption that the rows of both queries are in the same order and that order matters. If the data in query a)  is in different order than query b) you are likely to find differences.

Comment: @mortb looping on OracleDataReaders Read() method is what I was looking for, but, I can't compare (or I don't know how) without converting them into DataTables... Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt at writing a generic data comparison method for two `OracleDataReaders`. The code compares the readers line by line, column by column to spot any differences. It takes into account that readers may contain results from more than one query. Code will need to be enhanced if more complex datatypes (binary etc) would be compared. The code also makes the assumption that the order of the data matters; if readers are to be considered equal even when differently sorted the code would need to be rewritten to put rows into lists or dictionaries etc.

```
private bool ReadersContainEqualData(OracleDataReaders readerA, OracleDataReaders readerB)
{
    bool moreResultsA = false;
    bool moreResultsB = false;
    do {
        if(readerA.FieldCount != readerB.FieldCount)
        {
            return false; // the readers have different number of columns
        }
        while(readerA.Read() && readerB.Read())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < readerA.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if(readerA.GetName(i) != readerB.GetName(i)) // different column names, remove this check if it is not important to you
                {
                   return false;
                }
                if(readerA[i] != readerB[i]) // the columns are either string, numeric or booean, so simple equals comparison works. If more complex columns like varbinary etc is used, this check will need to be enhanced
                {
                    return false;
                }
           }
        }
        if(readerA.Read() || readerB.Read()) // one of the readers still has more rows and the other is empty
        {
            return false;
        }

        // check if the readers contains results from another query than the recently processed
        moreResultsA = readerA.NextResult();
        moreResultsB = readerB.NextResult();
        if(moreResultsA != moreResultsB)
        {
            return false;
        }
    } while(moreResultsA && moreResultsB);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try it and post results.
Thanks!